# Google map showing as gray box

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing this application for a drupal site. Using examples from the api site, I got the map to work fine with hardwired html with javascript  fixed in it. But I really need to use ajax and the ajax function with the same data is showing only the gray box.

Using alert() I have confirmed that the data is getting into the function properly via the ajax call, as is the map center and zoom. One key difference is that the hardwired html used an onload="fcn()" in the  tag as per google's examples, but I seem to need to use a jquery "jQuery(document).ready(function() {" in my .js file instead with no function defined. When I tried using the function, it never got triggered. Does this code require using a function? Admittedly I don't have a lot of javascript experience. Here is my js. The first row of the data has some parameters, the second the latitude, the third the longitude, and the last has the marker titles.

PS - not sure why I can't get the last set of }); to show in the code box.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.get('http://www.example/get_customer_geo', function(result) {

      var rows = result.split(';');
      var parms = rows[0].split(',');
      var midlat = parseFloat(parms[0]);
      var midlon = parseFloat(parms[1]);
      var LatlngCtr = new google.maps.LatLng(midlat,midlon);
      var zoomval = parms[2];
      var latitude = rows[1].split(',');
      var longitude = rows[2].split(',');
      var titles = rows[3].split(',');
      var myLatlng = new Array();
      var marker = new Array();

      for (i=0; i<latitude.length; i++)
      {
          myLatlng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latitude[i]),parseFloat(longitude[i]));
      }

      var myOptions = {
          zoom: zoomval,
          center: LatlngCtr,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_terr"), myOptions);

      for (i=0; i<latitude.length; i++)
      {
          marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng[i],
            map: map,
            title: titles[i]
          });

      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't use `<Body onload=“initialize()”>` either. I left the stock `function initialize ()` and just added this listener as the last part of my maps script `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);`

Comment: I tried replacing my "jQuery(document).ready(function() {" with a function declaration and adding your listener. I got the same behavior. I can display the arrays and MyOptions, but I wonder if there is a way to confirm the map instance is properly instanced.

Comment: Have you looked at it in Firebug to see if you are getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by making sure the coordinates of the map were defined. The reason my map was showing in gray was that the browser wasn't providing geolocation info. I set a default value for lat and long and the map appears now.